# How to solve an ODE with `odeint` using initial value from `fsolve`?

Tags: python, math, scipy, ode

I want to solve this ode with `odeint`, but the initial value for the ode should be a variable provided through `fsolve`. Any help is appreciated.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(u):
  return u+1

lam = 1
t = np.linspace(0,10,100)

def model(z,t):
  dzdt = -lam*f(z)-z/(t+1)
  return dzdt

def eqn(z0):
  return odeint(model, z0, t)

x =  fsolve(eqn, 1)
plt.plot(x,t)
plt.show()
```

I'm getting an error:

```
error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `odeint(model, z0, t)` with t being an nparray of 100 elements, gives as result an array with 100 elements, where each element is an array of one element as a result of the ODE.   Then, you are calling `fsolve` to find an `x` for which the ODE would be all zeros?   It is hard to grasp what is intended.

Comment: If I guessed correctly, you want to use the initial condition `z(100)=1` and obtain the solution over the interval `[0,100]`? You can do this without using `fsolve` by just integrating backwards, but a quick correction should be `def eqn(z0): return odeint(model, z0, t)[-1]`.